# setting a new parameter from a query disabled

Tags: parameters, powerquery

I can not choose a query as suggested values in '

> Manage Parameters

' (it's disabled).

I can choose one value, list of values but not a query.

Any ideas? Although I have 5 queries in the file, no drop-down, nothing listing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can only select queries that return lists.

```
let Source = {1..10}, TableName = Table.FromList(Source, each {_}, {"ColumnName"}), Result = TableName[ColumnName] in Result
```

Comment: can you be more specific ? 

and i have 2 queries which returns one-column lists already...

Comment: The query output must really be a list. If you mention 1 column then the query output may be a table with 1 column. A list doesn't have columns. Otherwise you can create a list from 1 table column.

Comment: can you give an example how to make a query (not a table) but a list instead from a one column table please...?

Comment: This query creates a list, converts it to a table and returns the table column as a list:

Comment: let
    Source = {1..10},
    TableName = Table.FromList(Source, each {_}, {"ColumnName"}),
    Result = TableName[ColumnName]
in
    Result

Comment: @MarcelBeug: In fact, it is enough of `let Source = {1..10} in Source`. 

And it seem to be buggy yet. It doesn't appear as a drop-down, and should you enter a value not in the list, it throws an unhandled error.

Comment: PowerQuery is painful, painful, painful when it comes to using Parameters.